# Increment (copy) a field for n record

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file which looks like this:

```
A a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
B a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
```

and the output should look like

```
A a
A b
A c
A d
A e
B a
B b
B c
B d
B e
```

This script:

```
awk {if ( NR%5 != 1 ) {print VAR, $2} else {print $1, $2} VAR=$1}
```

does not work (result below):

```
A a
A b
2 c
3 d
4 e
B a
B b
2 c
3 d
4 e
```

It seems I am missing something about the syntax, or the way variables work.
Is there a solution in awk scripting?

Thanks

Comment: Is it more like it now ?

Comment: You just need to move the `VAR=$1` assignment inside the `else` block, I think?

Comment: It that bash? You need 'quotes' around the awk script.

Comment: Edit the question and remove the line numbers, they're not part of the file according to your `awk` output.

Comment: The numbers 1. ... 2.... 10. are not part of the file but it does not make a difference if they would be. I am using Cygdrive to emulate unix console on windows 10.

Comment: Yes the VAR=$1 is inside the else block so that is should be executed only when awk reads every 5 lines, but the problem seems to be that VAR=$1 is executed also when the program is in the  (NR%5 != 1 ) phase.

Comment: @Raphaël Take a closer look... `VAR=$1` is *outside* the else block: `else{print ... } VAR=$1` the `print ...` is *inside*

Comment: Thank you "guest", it was indeed a syntax problem. Problem solved !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /^[[:upper:]]/ { letter = $1 } { $1 = letter; print }' file
A a
A b
A c
A d
A e
B a
B b
B c
B d
B e
```

This simply sets the variable `letter` to the value of the first field if it detects an upper-case character at the start of the field.  Then it, unconditionally, sets the first field to the saved data and prints the line.

Using your approach of picking up the first field every five lines, with a simplification:

```
$ awk 'FNR % 5 == 1 { letter = $1 } { $1 = letter; print }' file
A a
A b
A c
A d
A e
B a
B b
B c
B d
B e
```

In both variations I unconditionally set the first field to the value of `letter` and print the current record. This simplifies the code.

The main error in your code is that it sets `VAR` to `$1` for *every* input line:

```awk
{
    if ( NR%5 != 1 ) {
        print VAR, $2
    } else {
        print $1, $2
    }
    VAR = $1  # <-- problem: is triggered on every line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by below  script

```
step1: z=`awk 'END{print NR}' filename`
 step2: for ((i=1;i<=$z;i++)); do j=$(($i+4)); u=`awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{print $1}' o.txt`;sed -n ''$i','$j'p' filename| awk -v u="$u" '{$1=u;print $0}'; i=$j; done
```

output

```
A a
A b
A c
A d
A e
B a
B b
B c
B d
B e
```